# Phone Gap Build icon not updating

Tags: phonegap-build

I'm new to phone gap .. 
I'm facing a problem in updating the icon in my application 
whereas splash screens are updating fine

my app id is : 711301

And here is part of my config.xml file

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.7.0" />
<preference name="orientation"      value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen"       value="true" />.

<gap:platform name="ios" />
<gap:platform name="android" />
<gap:platform name="winphone" />


<icon src="icon.png" gap:role="default" />

<icon src="img/icons/ios/img-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="img/icons/ios/img-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="img/icons/ios/img-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="img/icons/ios/img-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="img/icons/android/img-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="img/icons/android/img-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="img/icons/android/img-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="img/icons/android/img-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="img/icons/winphone/img-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="img/icons/winphone/img-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" /> 




 <gap:splash src="splash.png" /> <!-- default 320x480 pixels -->

<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/splash320x480.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" /> <!-- iPhone & iPod Touch non retina -->
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/splash640x960.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" /> <!-- iPhone & iPod Touch retina 4- -->
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/splash640x1136.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" /> <!-- iPhone & iPod Touch retina 5+ -->
<!-- <gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/splash1024x768.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" /> iPad non retina --> 
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/splash768x1024.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" /> <!-- iPad non retina -->
<!-- <gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/splash2048x1496.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1496" /> iPad retina -->
<gap:splash src="img/splash/ios/splash1536x2008.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2008" /> <!-- iPad retina -->

<gap:splash src="img/splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" /> <!-- 200x320 -->
<gap:splash src="img/splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" /> <!-- 320x480 -->
<gap:splash src="img/splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" /> <!-- 480x800 -->
<gap:splash src="img/splash/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" /> <!-- 720x1280 -->

<gap:splash src="img/splash/winphone/splash.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" /> <!-- Windows Phone 7 480x800 -->
```

thanks

Comment: anyways i solved it :)

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: there were 2 problems ..
first the filename was wrong [a dumb thing i didnt noticed it :D ]
after that my project was not uploading to my online repository due to problem in my internet connection so phonegap build was pulling old project to rebuild each tym.. :)

Comment: Oh. Btw do you know how to make a hydrated app updates its icon without redownloading and reinstalling the app?

Comment: although this was my first experience with phonegap build but as well as i have experienced if u turn hydration on and rebuild the application next time u start the application hydration will automatically update the application with the updated version but ofcourse u should have hydration enabled on the build/app u r already using .. else it may not search for updates ..

Comment: Yea I know that and the app does update, but only the icon is not updating by itself.

Comment: have you checked he icon updation by directly downloading and installing it manually .. does the icon update??

Comment: btw there have been many issues with the icon thingy in phonegap build .. as i was searching for my solution ..

Comment: Reinstalling the app from the site will have the new icon applied, but not by in-app updates.

Comment: there could be two possibilities in my opinion .. 
either phonegap build is still not stable to update icon to an installed application or may be the application context is not allowing to replace the application resource like icon  .. 

chk this link:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_build_is_not_updating_all_of_my_files_when_it_runs

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the following structure 

my-app/
|__ res/
|__ www/
|__ config.xml
|__ icon.png
|__ splash.png
```